# Ref Updates And Fiber Triggers Using Cats Effect

Tags: scala, concurrency, atomic, scala-cats, cats-effect

**Problem:** *I am trying to solve a problem where I need to schedule for every x minutes, I need to update the cache and concurrent gets are possible.*

**Solutions tried:**

1. **Using TrieMap and ScheduledThreadPool Executor With Cats Effects:**

I actually started with using TrieMap as it provides thread safety and used scheduled thread pool for scheduling the update

```scala
import cats.Applicative.ops.toAllApplicativeOps
import cats.effect.concurrent.Ref
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp}

import java.util.concurrent.{Executors, ScheduledExecutorService}
import scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap
import scala.concurrent.duration.{DurationInt, FiniteDuration}
import scala.util.Random

object ExploreTrieMap extends IOApp {
  def callForEvery[A](f: => Unit, d: FiniteDuration)
                     (implicit sc: ScheduledExecutorService): IO[Unit] = {
    IO.cancelable {
      cb =>
        val r = new Runnable {
          override def run(): Unit = cb(Right(f))
        }
        val scFut = sc.scheduleAtFixedRate(r, 0, d.length, d.unit)
        IO(scFut.cancel(false)).void
    }
  }

  val map = TrieMap.empty[String, String]
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    implicit val scheduler: ScheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)
    for {
      _ <- callForEvery(println(map.get("token")), 1 second)
      _ <- callForEvery(println(map.put("token", Random.nextString(10))), 3 second)
    } yield ExitCode.Success
  }
}
```

2. **Using Ref and Cats Effect Fibers:**

And then created a pure cats-effect solution.

Will this below code end up in StackOverflow error?

```scala
import cats.effect.concurrent.Ref
import cats.effect.{ContextShift, ExitCode, Fiber, IO, IOApp}

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration.{DurationInt, FiniteDuration}
import scala.util.Random

object ExploreCatFiber extends IOApp {
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    for {
      ref <- Ref.of[IO, String]("")
      s <- scheduleAndPopulate(ref, 1 minute)
      r <- keepPollingUsingFiber(ref)
      _ <- s.join
      _ <- r.join
    } yield ExitCode.Success
  }

  def populate(): Future[String] = Future.successful(Random.nextString(10))

  val futPop = IO.fromFuture(IO(populate()))

  def scheduleAndPopulate(r: Ref[IO, String], duration: FiniteDuration)(implicit cs: ContextShift[IO]): IO[Fiber[IO, Unit]] = {
    (for {
      _ <- IO(println("Scheduled For Populating Ref"))
      res <- futPop
      _ <- r.set(res)
      _ <- IO.sleep(duration)
      rS <- scheduleAndPopulate(r, duration)(cs)
      _ <- rS.join
    } yield ()).start(cs)
  }


  def keepPollingUsingFiber(r: Ref[IO, String])(implicit cs: ContextShift[IO]): IO[Fiber[IO, Unit]] = {
    (for {
      res <- r.get
      _ <- IO(println(res))
      _ <- IO.sleep(1 second)
      w <- keepPollingUsingFiber(r)(cs)
      _ <- w.join
    } yield ()).start(cs)
  }
}
```

I'm trying to update a Ref, and use the Ref like a concurrent cache that is being updated by another fiber. And I'm triggering the fiber creation using recursion. I know fibers can be used for stacksafe operations. In this case, I'm joining on the old fiber created. So wanted to understand is the below code safe.

## Update (Solution from answers provided below)

Third solution: Based on input from one of the answers. Rather than forking for each recursive call, fork it on the caller.

```scala
import cats.effect.concurrent.Ref
import cats.effect.{ContextShift, ExitCode, Fiber, IO, IOApp}

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration.{DurationInt, FiniteDuration}
import scala.util.Random

object ExploreCatFiberWithIO extends IOApp {
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    for {
      ref <- Ref.of[IO, String]("")
      s <- scheduleAndPopulateWithIO(ref, 1 second).start
      r <- keepPollingUsingIO(ref).start
      _ <- s.join
      _ <- r.join
    } yield ExitCode.Success
  }

  def populate(): Future[String] = Future.successful(Random.nextString(10))

  val futPop = IO.fromFuture(IO(populate()))

  def scheduleAndPopulateWithIO(r: Ref[IO, String], duration: FiniteDuration)(implicit cs: ContextShift[IO]): IO[Unit] = {
    for {
      _ <- IO(println("Scheduled For Populating Ref"))
      res <- futPop
      _ <- r.set(res)
      _ <- IO.sleep(duration)
      _ <- scheduleAndPopulateWithIO(r, duration)(cs)
    } yield ()
  }

  def keepPollingUsingIO(r: Ref[IO, String])(implicit cs: ContextShift[IO]): IO[Unit] = {
    (for {
      res <- r.get
      _ <- IO(println(res))
      _ <- IO.sleep(1 second)
      w <- keepPollingUsingIO(r)(cs)
    } yield ())
  }
}
```

***Would love to know the pros and cons of the approaches discussed above.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second approach, you can make it simpler by not forking a `Fiber` in `scheduleAndPopulate` and `keepPollingUsingFiber`. Instead, keep the recursive call, and fork them in the caller. `IO` is stack-safe, so the recursive call won't blow up the stack.

You could use `start` to fork each, but it might be simpler to `parTupled` them. It's a variation of `parMapN` that forks each effect and gathers their results.

(Also, in your code you don't need to pass the implicit values, like `cs`, explicitly, the compiler will infer them for you.)

```scala
object ExploreCatFiber extends IOApp {
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    for {
      ref <- Ref.of[IO, String]("")
      _ <- (scheduleAndPopulate(ref, 1 minute), keepPollingUsingFiber(ref)).parTupled
    } yield ExitCode.Success
  }

  def populate(): Future[String] = Future.successful(Random.nextString(10))

  val futPop = IO.fromFuture(IO(populate()))

  def scheduleAndPopulate(r: Ref[IO, String], duration: FiniteDuration): IO[Unit] = {
    (for {
      _ <- IO(println("Scheduled For Populating Ref"))
      res <- futPop
      _ <- r.set(res)
      _ <- IO.sleep(duration)
      _ <- scheduleAndPopulate(r, duration)
    } yield ()
  }

  def keepPollingUsingFiber(r: Ref[IO, String]): IO[Unit] = {
    (for {
      res <- r.get
      _ <- IO(println(res))
      _ <- IO.sleep(1 second)
      _ <- keepPollingUsingFiber(r)
    } yield ()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you please explain the pros and cons for both of the above approaches asked in the question?

Comment: Adam, I have updated the question with your proposed solution as well.